# Chai - expect function to throw error

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm quite new to Chai so I'm still getting to grips with things.

I have written function that will check an API response and return either the correct messaging or throw an error.

```
networkDataHelper.prototype.formatPostcodeStatus = function(postcodeStatus) {

if (postcodeStatus.hasOwnProperty("errorCode")) {
    //errorCode should always be "INVALID_POSTCODE"
    throw Error(postcodeStatus.errorCode);
}

if (postcodeStatus.hasOwnProperty("lori")) {
    return "There appears to be a problem in your area. " + postcodeStatus.lori.message;
}

else if (postcodeStatus.maintenance !== null) {
    return postcodeStatus.maintenance.bodytext;
}

else {
    return "There are currently no outages in your area.";
}
};
```

I've managed to write tests for the messaging, however, I'm struggling with the error test. Here's what I've written to date:

```
var networkDataHelper = require('../network_data_helper.js');

describe('networkDataHelper', function() {
var subject = new networkDataHelper();
var postcode;

    describe('#formatPostcodeStatus', function() {
        var status = {
            "locationValue":"SL66DY",
            "error":false,
            "maintenance":null,
        };

        context('a request with an incorrect postcode', function() {
            it('throws an error', function() {
                status.errorCode = "INVALID_POSTCODE";
                expect(subject.formatPostcodeStatus(status)).to.throw(Error);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the test above, I get the following error message:

> 1) networkDataHelper #formatPostcodeStatus a request with an incorrect postcode throws an error: Error: INVALID_POSTCODE

It seems like the error that is being thrown is causing the test to fail, but I'm not too sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the caveat that I'm no Chai expert, the construct you have:

```
expect(subject.formatPostcodeStatus(status)).to.throw(Error);
```

cannot possibly handle the thrown exception before the Chai framework gets around to seeing your `.to.throw()` chain. The code above *calls* the function *before* the call to `expect()` is made, so the exception happens too soon.

Instead, you should pass a function to `expect()`:

```
expect(function() { subject.formatPostCodeStatus(status); })
  .to.throw(Error);
```

That way, the framework can invoke the function *after* it's prepared for the exception.

Comment: Of course! All working as expected now. Thank you for the informative answer and code snippet; I understand why the issue occured and your solution is working perfectly.